# How do I convert an IP address to a binary(16) string?

Tags: mysql, binary

I need to know how to convert an IP address to a binary(16) string. I need this to use in a MySql database but the conversion doesn't necessary need be an sql statement/query.

Comment: "or any other string"?

Comment: Why would you want to store addresses as binary strings? These are much harder to search and deal with, and the space savings is so minor that it's really not worth it. MySQL is incapable of dealing with binary form IP addreses, they're just data as far as its concerned. Keep in mind other databases like Postgres have native IP column types that have robust support.

Comment: I have a MySql table with this field and I want to manually insert the value of an IP into it. I didn't design and can't change the way it is - I just need the IP string converted to the binary(16) string.

Answer (score -2):

IPv4 addresses requires min 4 bytes (32 bits ) in memory. So in case you are looking to store the address in 2bytes of space then its possible if you're organisation has subnet and netmask is 255.255.x.x or 255.255.255.x. In this just store the host part in the database.

eg 10.80.100.26 netmask 255.255.255.0 then just store 26 in your database.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: IPv4 addresses require *exactly* four bytes. Very few organizations are split along a single CIDR subnet, it's common you'll have multiple, completely unrelated ones. Storing host only is asking for a world of trouble.

Comment: Thats Right. But given his limitation and if he's lucky( Single CIDR subnet) then he can use this way to store in 2 bytes.

Comment: That suggestion is just plain wrong. Nobody does this and for good reason. It's utterly absurd. Saving two bytes and adding massive confusion is a really terrible trade-off.